# ProFTPd with sftp first login fails, seconds succeeds

Tags: ftp, sftp, proftpd

We are working with ProFTPd and SFTP module enabled. We have a problem with using the sftp module.

When we try to connect to server in FileZilla we need to enter the password to the server twice, upon connection and upon each file upload, which is very undesired. How can we help this? any idea's? suggestions?

when we use the interactive login type in FileZilla, it works when we enter the username and password twice.

Comment: Have you tried any other clients besides FileZilla?

Answer (score 3):

If you're experiencing the same issue as I am you will find in your server's auth log that proftpd first tries pam_unix before falling back to the configured authentication method. For me I am using authuserfile and not Unix authentication. As with you my first attempts always fail and the second attempts always succeed.

The proftpd documentation would have you believe that `AuthPAM off` disables pam authentication entirely. I find this to be inaccurate as proftpd continues to try pam even with `AuthPAM off` and `PersistendPassed off`.

I recompiled proftpd without pam and now I can login the first time. The problem is that most distributions ship binary packages and may not even give you this ability. If that is the case then you could always modify pam to use the authentication method you require.

Comment: If you are using the `mod_sftp` module, then the PAM support is a little different; it's via the `mod_sftp_pam` module.  This, in turns, means that to disable PAM usage for SFTP logins, you would use `SFTPPAMEngine off` in the `mod_sftp` config.  I agree, though, that this is confusing, and that having `mod_sftp_pam` pay attention to the `AuthPAM` directive would help.

Comment: This has now been [changed/fixed](https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/commit/4df35f9dbf373a545af910a5d5d3f7046a124a86) in proftpd.